# run method using window.location with asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

Is it possible to have a server-side click handler for a hyperlink?

Comment: Hi Rod, as per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts , salutations/sign-offs are generally considered superfluous on stackoverflow, hence I've removed them when I tidied up your question =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider converting your hyperlink, perhaps it's an `<a>` tag, to a ASP.NET server side control: [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx).

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="foo"   OnClick="LinkButton_Click" 
     Text="Do Some Stuff Server Side, and Expect a Redirect Somewhere" />
```

It's not clear from the question what you'd like to do server side. From here, you can call custom code and basically do anything once it's posted back.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're after ASP.net Web Methods, there's an example [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200803212711/http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx).

Basically, you decorate a method in your code-behind with the `System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod` and `System.Web.Script.Services.WebMethod` attributes, which means that you can then call the method from javascript.

Comment: Now you've edited your question to clarify that you want a handler for a hyperlink, p.campbell's answer is more what you need =)